# Program runs on HTC Incredible, crashes within 1-2 seconds on Droid X2

Tags: android

On the X2 my program crashes after a second. I notice that onCreate()/onStart()/onResume() are called, however onPause()/onStop()/onDestroy() are not, even though the program is no longer running. The logcat error messages don't point to a specific line as the problem...they are something like:

```
    Communications error
    java.io.IOException: no such file or directory
    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connectLocal(Native Method)
    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connect(LocalSocketImp.java:238)
    ...
    at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.listenToSocket(NativeDaemonConnector)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
    Error in NativeDaemonConnector
```

And the tag for all these is either `TundConnector` or `NetLinkEvent`.

I have no idea why its doing this or how to fix it. There is no socket programming involved in the program. Could someone please give me a nudge in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: If all else fails you can try to write a lot of trace messages to find what the last thing working is exactly and deduce what breaks.

Comment: @sharptooth -- good back up strategy.

Comment: What evidence do you have that the stack trace you cite has anything whatsoever to do with your app?

Comment: Apparently its an OpenGL problem. The transparency code I wrote isn't in harmony with the x2. @CommonsWare -- because I clear the logcat, then when I start the program the logcat is flooded with the exceptions.

Comment: Debug step through your app, put a breakpoint in the first line of onCreate.